# Air flow through a penny whistle

Tags: acoustics, resonance

I am confused about exactly how air flows through a penny whistle. I would also like to double check that I understand correctly what the cavity of resonance is.

Say I have a whistle like this:

```
          –  ––––––––––––– –– –– –– ––– ––– ––– ––
Mouthpiece
          ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

---

The `x`s indicate closed holes. Would the following diagram show correctly the flow of air through this flute?

```
            o                      o
          – /–––––––––––––x––x––x––/––– ––– ––– ––
Mouthpiece-/----------------------/ -    -    -    -
          ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Would the cavity of resonance be from the first `o` to the second `o`?

Would the sound come out of those cavities because that's where the pressure difference is greatest, so that is where a strong oscillation occurs? If so, then why doesn't such an oscillation occur at the subsequent holes?

---

What about the following diagram?

```
          –  ––––––––––––– ––x––x–– ––– ––– ––– ––
Mouthpiece
          ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

I'm not sure what this air flow should look like, and therefore I have no idea what the cavity of resonance would be.

---

Is the first diagram correct? What would the airflow and and cavity of resonance of the second one look like?

Comment: The cavity is the whole tube. The fingering of the holes determines what modes of that air column will have a strong resonance.

Comment: @Pieter, could you please explain how that works? I’m a bit confused as to what you mean by the “mode of that air column”

Comment: With all holes closed, the flute is a cylindrical tube open on both sides. There are then standing waves because of reflections on both sides. The fundamental mode is half a wavelength, but there are also resonances at the harmonic frequencies (with one wavelength in the tube, or $3/2 \lambda$, $2\lambda$, etc). These are the resonant modes. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Onde_stationnaire_tuyau_ouvert_trois_modes_petit.gif

Comment: But I might be wrong. When all holes in the far end of the flute are open, there is not much resonance there. See this page by Bolton: http://www.flute-a-bec.com/colonnedair-re1-gb.html

Comment: @Pieter, what happens when some of the holes in the far end are closed? From the picture on that page, it seems that the resonance cavity ends about where the first hole is.

Comment: I do not know if there are real measurements or good simulations for that. But a single open hole should mostly affect which of the resonant modes of the air column get a stronger resonance and which ones are weaker.  And then there is a complicated feedback to the airflow in the mouthpiece which is driving the resonances.

Comment: @Pieter, from experiment though it seems that the fundamental frequency does in fact change. Is that not right or impossible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76075/discussion-between-pieter-and-dopapp).